# Setting up Django application on Hetzner Managed Server

Tags: python, django, server, web-applications, managed

I have a managed server from Hetzner for my wordpress websites and now I want to deploy a django application on it without renting a cloud server from hetzner.

The application runs on my computer with localhost on the browser, but on the server it only shows the index.html page with the right css styling. When I try to use e.g. buttons on the page it throws me "The requested URL was not found on this server." because the links are with "/reg/" and when the django isn't running right it can't access the other pages.

I've set up a cronjob on the server "'/usr/bin/python3 /usr/home/username/public_html/testbox/manage.py'" and that seems to work fine according to the hetzner dashboard. In addition, Python and django are installed on the subdomain.

Is there another thing e.g. docker or nginx that I am missing?

Thanks in advance.